# Log4j 1.2 TimeBasedRollingPolicy fails to rollover files when application is restarted during rollover period

Tags: logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

We're using a TimeBasedRollingPolicy on a RollingFileAppender to roll logs daily.  I noticed some gaps in the rolled files occurring on days that our servers were restarted (usually spanning midnight).  The subsequent roll has both days' logs.

Does the TimeBasedRollingPolicy not account for downtime spanning the normal roll window?  Is there a way to resolve this without writing a custom policy?

We're using a prepackaged framework (Liferay) and injecting custom jars into its lib is not ideal.

---

Log4j: 1.2.16, Log4j-extras: 1.1

```
<appender name="EXAMPLE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/example/logs/example.log" />

    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/example/logs/example.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="EXAMPLE-ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE"/>
</appender>

<logger name="com.company.example" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="EXAMPLE-ASYNC" />
</logger>
```

[Here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#rfa) is the log4j 1.2 FAQ regarding common rollover issues, none of which apply.